# Can a LP optimization problem have exactly two solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example a linear model defined by equation
Min[5 x + 7 y,8 x + 4 y] <= 7 - 5 x
has a feasible region shown as below.

This model forms a concave feasible region that has two corner points (x_1,y_1), 〖(x〗_2,y_2) and in the second and fourth quadrant respectively.  Let's say our objective function is of the form 
ax+by=c,where a>0,b>0 and c is the value we wish to maximize.

Also,
ax_1+by_1=c
ax_2+by_2=c

The maximum value of our 'c' will be achieved only at these two points and nowhere else. Hence, we can have exactly two optimal solutions.

Sub Question:
1) Is the region defined by Min function correctly defines a Linear model?

Comment: Your problem in not a linear program.  You cannot express your constraint by a collection of linear inequalities.  It is actually a somewhat complicated logical constraint.Linear programs have convex feasible regions; yours does not.

Comment: I decided to make the above an answer instead of a comment.  Is there some way to delete a comment?  I can't find anything in MSE help about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in not a linear program.  You cannot express your constraint by a collection of linear inequalities.  It is actually a somewhat complicated logical constraint.

Linear programs have convex feasible regions; yours does not.

If a linear program has more than one solution, it has infinitely many, as all convex combinations will be solutions.

I would not consider this to be a linear-algebra question.  More like operations research.

Comment: Actually, the logic is not that complicated.  Your constraint is equivalent to $5x + 7y \le 7 - 5x$ *or* $8x + 4y \le 7 - 5x$.  In an LP, you must have a conjunction (and) of linear inequalities.  No disjunctions (or) are allowed.